# PHP project, linux configuration

Tags: linux, apache, architecture, configuration

I hope this is the right place to ask.

Here is my scenario for developing php project:

I have 2 machines. One with Linux(ubuntu) and one with Windows 7 connected via local network.

Linux is my apache server and windows is my editing machine.

I have managed to configure properly linux machine and I can use http://myproject url on Windows machine to see my project.

**I need to use Windows for editing files (netbeans) and my question is what do I need to use/install on linux to be able to edit instantly files and use http://myproject to see changes?**

Please make a note that I dont want to use SVN/Git for this I just want to be able to edit files quickly and see changes via http://myproject. Please make another note that there are other machines on the network and I expect at least minimum password protection (when saving changes).

Please help me finding the best solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use webDAV:

```
Dav On
DavLockDB /usr/local/apache2/var/DavLock

<Location /foo>
  Dav On

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName DAV
  AuthUserFile user.passwd

  <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
    require user admin
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Then on the client computer, Map a network drive to your web folder similar to these instruction:

http://help.wildapricot.com/display/DOC/Setting+Up+WebDAV+in+Windows+7

Good luck!

Comment: Looks like a not bad idea, I will try to configure and let you know how did it go. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable FTP on your linux box. [set up FTP on ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-an-FTP-Server-in-Ubuntu-Linux)

Then get some FTP client like FileZilla for your windows system. install it, connect to your newly created FTP server and you are done.
I am not sure about how to connect netbeans to ftp, but you can use some file editing tools like PSPad which provides inbuilt FTP support. Alternatively if you can use eclipse it supports FTP transfer for sure.

Comment: FTP is too slow :( I think im going to use samba and restrict to IP addres by using: allow hosts 192.168.1.2

Comment: Over a local network, FTP will be fast enough. Just make sure that your editor supports FTP.

Comment: my netbeans does support ftp but its too slow to me :(